# how to Put div to same Position on reload and load using jquery 1.5.2

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I wanted to know if there was an easy way to change the div position when i refresh my browser I don't want to lose the place that I have changed to i have 3 Div (Div1 Logo - Div2 Text - Div3 Langue) I want to change Div2 and Div3 when witdh page <=765 and refresh and don't lose this position (Div1 -Div2 -Div3)

```
$(document).load($(window).bind("resize", listenWidth));
 function listenWidth( e ) {
    if($(window).width() <= 765)
    {
        $(".welcomeheader1").remove().insertAfter($(".welcomeheader2"));
    } else {
        $(".welcomeheader1").remove().insertBefore($(".welcomeheader2"));
    }
}
```

HTML Code

```
<div id="header" class="header clearfix">
<div class="row clearfix">
    <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-4 xs-last txtRight">
        <div id="headerLogo" ></div>
    </div>
    <div id="welcome" class="txtCenter col-lg-6 col-md-7 col-sm-12 col-12 clearfix welcomeheader1">
        <!--    <img src="./resources/_images/wifi.png?1595436503" class="wifi-img" alt="WIFI" /> -->
        <!--
        <div class="wifi-symbol">
            <div class="wifi-circle first"></div>
            <div class="wifi-circle second"></div>
            <div class="wifi-circle third"></div>
            <div class="wifi-circle fourth"></div>
        </div>
        -->
        <img class="wifi_welcome" src="./resources/_images/wifi_welcome.png?1590753851" alt="">
        <h1 id="welcomeHeadline">WELCOME</h1>
        <h2 id="connectezvous">Connectez-vous au Wifi gratuit</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-2 col-sm-6 col-8 welcomeheader2 " align="Right">
        <div id="lang_block">
            <i id="showLanguages">&nbsp;<span id="language_text_id">Langue</span>&nbsp;<img class="left_arrow" src="./resources/_images/left-arrow.png?1590753851" alt=""></i>
            <div id="langContainer">
                <a id="lang_link[en]" href="#" style="display:none"><img src="./resources/_images/flags/en.png?1595436503" title="English"></a>
                <a id="lang_link[fr]" href="#" style="display:none"><img src="./resources/_images/flags/fr.png?1595436503" title="Fran&ccedil;ais"></a>
            </div>
        </div>
    &nbsp;
    </div>
</div>

<div class="clear"></div>
<!-- The header template -->
<!-- Will be added on top of the page -->
```

Comment: You could just trigger a resize on window when the page loads $(window).trigger("resize"). That would run your js listeWidth function once. If you actually want to save the position you should look into localstorage

Comment: what ancient version of jQuery are you  using that you are using bind? Also that bind/resize is not being called onload.....

Comment: using jqeury 1.5.2 !

Comment: Only 10 years old....

Comment: i can't change jquery because i work on portal and this portal all the code js with jquery 1.5.2 when i change version appear a lot of bug

Answer (score 1):

So call the function on load

```
$(document).load( function () {
  listenWidth();
  $(window).bind("resize", listenWidth)
});
```

Comment: tahnk you for help